# -bash: fork: retry: no child processes

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I'm having issues with my University server. I'm new to C++ in UNIX and we are looking at forks/execs. I ran the following code, and now every time I try to work in the terminal I get multiple instances of bash: fork: retry: no child processes.

How do I fix this? Does it have something to do with my userlimit processes? I've googled extensively but to no avail. It also sometimes gives me that the resource is temporarily unavailable.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

        string input;


        do
        {
                int pid;


                cout << "# ";
                getline(cin, input);
                //cout << "Your input was: " << input << endl;


                if(input == "exit")
                {
                        break;
                }

                pid = fork();

                if (pid == 0)
                {
                        cout << "child" << endl;
                }

                cout << "done" << endl;
```

Comment: why call fork()?

Comment: This is not a bash problem.

Comment: We're missing some code at the bottom, but almost certainly the issue is that you have a whole bunch of processes running that never died, and you reached the maximum number you're allowed to have. Ask the sysadmin of the university server to kill them all, or run `exec killall <whatever_your_program_filename_is>` in Bash.

Comment: what is the `while` condition? Looks like you've made a fork bomb.